# IE10 - Missing borders until a click action

Tags: border, internet-explorer-10, html-table

In IE10 there is a strange bug that causes some borders to not appear when the page loads.  Oddly enough, they do appear when you click within the page and or in the area they should be displaying.

Has anyone experienced this and figured out how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The borders not appearing until onclick in IE10 is a bug caused by using border-collapse and colspan.

The workaround/fix I used was to create a row with one cell adding display none to it.  This row and cell needs to be placed above the offending colspan row/cell.

Code Example...

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="4" style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="4" style="display: none;">
      Your content here
   </td>
</tr>
```